# how to code in polars python with the following tidyverse R code?

Tags: python, r, dplyr, tidyverse, python-polars

I want migrate my application from R using tidyvers to Python Polars, what equivalent of this code in python polars?

```
new_table <- table1 %>%
  mutate(no = row_number()) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(c, d), ~ifelse(no %in% c(2,5,7), replace_na(., 0), .)) %>%
  mutate(e = table2$value[match(a, table2$id)],
         f = ifelse(no %in% c(3,4), table3$value[match(b, table3$id)], f))
```

I try see the polars document for combining data and selecting data but still do not undestand

Comment: Can you add a minimal example dataset and expected output?

Comment: I don't have the dataset, the above code is about add column called no and assign row number of table1 dataframe to it, then manipulating existing column c and d of table1 dataframe on spesific row(2,5,7) to 0 if the value null or na if not just take value c or d, then manipulating existing column e of table1 dataframe assign it with value from another table2 dataframe with key on table1 a and table2 Id, then manipulating existing column f of table1 dataframe assign it with value from table3 on spesific row 3 and 4 with key on table1 b and table3 id

Comment: You're going to need to work harder than that.  Make up some data for `table1`, `table2`, and `table3` that have the variables that are being worked on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I expressed the assignment from the other tables as a join (actually I would have done this in tidyverse as well). Otherwise the translation is straight forward. You need:

- `with_row_count` for the row numbers
- `with_columns` to mutate columns
- `pl.col` to reference columns
- `pl.when.then.otherwise` for conditional expressions
- `fill_nan` to replace NaN values

```
(table1
    .with_row_count("no", 1)
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col("no").is_in([2, 5, 7]))
        .then(pl.col(["c", "d"]).fill_nan(0))
        .otherwise(pl.col(["c", "d"]))
    )
    .join(table2, how="left", left_on="a", right_on="id")
    .rename({"value": "e"})
    .join(table3, how="left", left_on="b", right_on="id")
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col("no").is_in([3, 4]))
        .then(pl.col("value"))
        .otherwise(pl.col("f"))
        .alias("f")
    )
    .select(pl.exclude("value")) # drop the joined column table3["value"] 
)
```

Comment: Yes, with this code I can achieve the goal, but I think with add column join then assign value to correct column then remove it again it's like extra work, is there direct slicing like in r  table3$value[match(b, table3$id)] and put it directly to correct column ? But I will take this as an answer, Thanks

Comment: You could try to replicate the behaviour of match, but actually it involves more "work" than the proposed solution: match first builds up a list with the index values of the matching entries and then gets the values based on this index list. Joining and dropping a column should be cheaper.

Comment: Quite good translation I think. Potentially table2 and table3 contains other columns which could be added to exclude.